# Post isn't sending data do mySql table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm new at programming and I've been trying to make a post that allows me to send data from an ancount form into a table( mysql database). However the console.log(on the node node console shows me an error) and I can't seem to understand why the post isn't working.

I get the error cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake, even though I've googled about, I haven't found a way to make the post work or get rid of this error.

Appreciate for any help.

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Create connection
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'nodemysql'
});

// Connect
db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('MySql Connected...');
});

const app = express();


app.get('/', function (req, res) {//nome da minha url  req(é o que vai na url/ res é o response é o ficheiro)
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
})

app.get('/log_in', function (req, res) {//nome da minha url
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/signin.html'));
})

app.get('/register', function (req, res) {//nome da minha url
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/register.html'));
})

// Create DB
app.get('/createdb', (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS nodemysql';
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Database created...');
    });
});

// Create table
app.get('/createusertable', (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'CREATE TABLE user (id int AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50), last_name VARCHAR(50),email VARCHAR(100),password VARCHAR (100),phone VARCHAR (50),country VARCHAR(100),vat_number VARCHAR(9),address VARCHAR(150), PRIMARY KEY(id))';
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Post table created...');
    });
});

  db.connect(function(err){
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('conectou!');
  createTable(connection);
})

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});


app.use(express.static('public'))
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());


    app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.user.name);
    let post = {name:req.body.user.name, last_name:req.body.user.lastName,
    email:req.body.user.email, password:req.body.user.password, phone:req.body.user.phone,
    country:req.body.user.country, vat_number:req.body.user.nif, address:req.body.user.address};

    let sql = 'INSERT INTO user SET ?';
    let query = db.query(sql, post, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
   res.redirect(303,'/');

});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you initiate another db.connect in your create table step after you already initiated a connect in the beginning of your script.

This is a double connection initiation, without any connection.end(); to close the initially opened connection.

I think you will have more luck when you remove the db.connect from your "create table" step.

Please view [this documentation](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/nodejs-tutorials/nodejs-mysql-error-cannot-enqueue-handshake-after-already-enqueuing-a-handshake) to further clarify my point.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thank you a lot. I got your answer as correct.

Comment: I see you set some variables after you do a seemingly empty post to '/register'

The actions you specified in the let variable are never returned/executed.

you have to add a return; to it to execute your specified code.

    let query = db.query(sql, post, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
       res.redirect(303,'/');
return query;

Comment: It's not working yet, neither the console.log() on node is working on this post